# Can't kill workers after running R script

Tags: r, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, snowfall

I am using: R Version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) and snowfall 1.84-4 initialized (using snow 0.3-13) on an m2.2xl AWS EC2 with the original AMI coming from http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/ .

My problem is that after creating a cluster using:

```
sfInit(parallel=TRUE,cpus=4, type="SOCK",socketHosts=rep("localhost",4) 
sfExport('dataframe') 
answer=sfSapply(dataframe, some_function) 
sfStop()
```

From command line I run: 
`sudo R CMD BATCH xyz.R &`

If xyz.R ever fails all of the nodes continue to exist, but now I am unable to use sfStop() because I ran the file as a script. If I run the same code within the Rstudio browser window I can successfully run sfStop() if the code ever fails.

If I include

```
tryCatch(
  {sfInit(parallel=TRUE,cpus=4, type="SOCK",socketHosts=rep("localhost",4) 
    sfExport('dataframe') 
    answer=sfSapply(dataframe, some_function) 
  },error=function(e){
    print(conditionMessage(e))
    sfStop()
  }
)
```

Then it catches any errors and kills the cluster. Also if I only run the commands from Rstudio I can stop the cluster. The issue however still remains that I have 30+ nodes that were started using scripts and can't be stopped.

I have tried to kill the nodes using `sudo kill 'PID' -9`, but they always just reappear. I've also tried by killing all of PPID=2. I tried rebooting my EC2, but that didn't do the trick either. I have even went so far as to manually kill every process that was running (yes, all 100+ of them), but these PPID=2 all come back. This is the output of `ps -ef`. The bottom shows my current cluster of 8 that is working.

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 15:47 ?        00:00:02 /sbin/init
root         2     0  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0]
root         5     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         6     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u:0]
root         7     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u:0H]
root         8     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [migration/0]
root         9     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_bh]
root        10     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_sched]
root        11     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/0]
root        12     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/1]
root        13     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        14     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [migration/1]
root        15     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0]
root        16     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0H]
root        17     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/2]
root        18     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
root        19     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [migration/2]
root        20     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0]
root        21     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0H]
root        22     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/3]
root        23     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
root        24     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [migration/3]
root        25     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:0]
root        26     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:0H]
root        27     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [cpuset]
root        28     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [khelper]
root        29     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        30     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [netns]
root        31     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [xenwatch]
root        32     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [xenbus]
root        33     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [bdi-default]
root        34     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd]
root        35     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd]
root        36     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:1]
root        37     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [ata_sff]
root        38     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [khubd]
root        39     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [md]
root        40     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [devfreq_wq]
root        41     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:1]
root        43     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [khungtaskd]
root        44     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kswapd0]
root        45     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [ksmd]
root        46     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        47     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root        48     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [crypto]
root        59     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld]
root        60     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u:1]
root        61     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [khvcd]
root        62     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:1]
root        63     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:1]
root        64     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [binder]
root        83     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [deferwq]
root        84     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [charger_manager]
root       237     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/xvda1-8]
root       238     2  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       270     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 mountall --daemon
root       289     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 upstart-file-bridge --daemon
root       372     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
root       374     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       535     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
root       635     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /
root       833     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
syslog     888     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 rsyslogd -c5
102        952     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon --system --fork
root       963     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/modem-manager
root       978     1  0 15:47 tty4     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
root       984     1  0 15:47 tty5     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
root      1012     1  0 15:47 tty2     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root      1017     1  0 15:47 tty3     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
root      1020     1  0 15:47 tty6     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
avahi     1036     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: running [ip-10-0-0-92.local]
root      1040     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.soc
avahi     1042  1036  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
root      1047     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
root      1065     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 cron
daemon    1066     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 atd
root      1339   374  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root      1340   374  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
mysql     1342     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root      1381     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -F
root      1391     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager
whoopsie  1405     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 whoopsie
999       1406     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver
root      1414     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
root      1427     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: accepting connections
root      1561     1  0 15:47 tty1     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
root      1758   833  0 15:51 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ubuntu [priv]
root      1760     2  0 15:52 ?        00:00:00 [kauditd]
root      1762     1  0 15:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon
ubuntu    1899  1758  0 15:52 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ubuntu@pts/0
ubuntu    1900  1899  0 15:52 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
rstudio   1988  1406  3 15:53 ?        00:03:05 /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rsession -u rstudio
rstudio   2146     1  4 16:06 ?        00:03:28 /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R --slave --no-restore --fi
rstudio   2153     1 19 16:06 ?        00:15:18 /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R --slave --no-restore --fi
rstudio   2160     1 32 16:06 ?        00:25:38 /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R --slave --no-restore --fi
rstudio   2167     1 56 16:06 ?        00:44:52 /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R --slave --no-restore --fi
rstudio   2174     1 63 16:06 ?        00:50:28 /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R --slave --no-restore --fi
rstudio   2181     1 66 16:06 ?        00:52:09 /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R --slave --no-restore --fi
rstudio   2188     1 66 16:06 ?        00:52:37 /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R --slave --no-restore --fi
rstudio   2195     1 64 16:06 ?        00:50:53 /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R --slave --no-restore --fi
root      2326     2  0 17:00 ?        00:00:00 [flush-202:1]
ubuntu    2371  1900  0 17:25 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

The top 50 processes exist/will come back regardless of what I do. Has anyone else had this problem? If so, how did you kill the workers?

Comment: What if you restart the instance? That should normally kill all processes.

Comment: 'I tried rebooting my EC2, but that didn't do the trick either.' I believe because the EC2 automatically saves the work-space, some part of the work-space continues to refresh these particular processes upon start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are put off guard by the term worker. When running R analyses in parallel, it is not `kworker` processes that are spawned but R processes. This is also what you observe in the `ps -ef` output.

[The `kworker` processes are simply part of the Linux system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33640/kworker-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-hogging-so-much-cpu), and are unrelated to parallel processing in R. The fact that these processes respawn after a reboot is a good indication of this, R workers would never do that (unless you add an R script that launches the workers in your startup config).

Comment: I think that is exactly the problem. After struggling with this issue I thought I was dealing with I finally just used `top` and saw that all those 50 little guys were utilizing 0 %CPU and 0 RES. So at this point they are simply annoying. Thanks for your quick reply!